# I recently started a new job,one of my male colleagues keeps referring to me as trouble. 'Hello trouble, how are you trouble'. What does this mean?

Tags: phrase-request

He keeps ringing me up saying, 'Hello trouble', or 'bye trouble. I don't understand it. I've never heard of this as a nickname

Comment: You've never heard the expression, "Here comes trouble"? It's something someone says to playfully tease someone else they see coming their way for being a troublemaker, but it's often said ironically, like to someone who isn't a troublemaker. What it sounds like this colleague is doing is playing off that, possibly because he once said "Here comes trouble" to you and you reacted in a way that he enjoyed, so he's taken it to another level by nicknaming you "Trouble." That's just my guess. It's not an answer because you haven't provided enough context to give a fact-based answer.

Comment: As posed this is unanswerable.  But if someone at work is making you uncomfortable, you have a right to ask them to stop, and be supported by your organisation.

Comment: It may suffice just to ask, without smiling, why they are addressing you that way, since you do have a name.

Comment: In the UK, 'trouble' is a friendly nickname for a child, friend, colleague, etc. It doesn't mean that the speaker thinks you are troublesome.

Comment: Could be a bit camp, actually.